Batch/many delete using SQLiteOpenHelper not working
I'm trying to batch-delete all of the records in a list of ids using SQLiteOpenHelper without luck. This is something like what I had in my code:
class DBHelper(context: Context?, factory: SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory?) :
    SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION) {

    ...

    private fun <T>buildIdsArguments(ids: Array<T>): Pair<Array<String>, String> {
        val args = mutableListOf<String>()
        val placeholders = mutableListOf<String>()
        for (id in ids) {
            args.add("'$id'")
            placeholders.add("?")
        }
        return Pair(args.toTypedArray(), placeholders.joinToString())
    }

    fun <T>deleteMany(db: SQLiteDatabase, table: DBTable, ids: Array<T>) {
        val (args, placeholders) = buildIdsArguments(ids)
        val deleted = db.delete(table.name, "id in ($placeholders)", args)
        if (deleted != ids.size) {
            throw Exception("An error occurred while deleting the records")
        }
    }
}

I'm trying to call the deleteMany method of the DBHelper class and I'm always getting the "An error occurred while deleting the records" error I set in case the number of deleted records don't match the number of ids.
Do you know what I'm doing wrong?
